# Get a Property Type without an Instance

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there a way through reflection to get the type of a property without instantiating the class?

I have two string variables, one holding the class name and one holding the property name. I then need to get the property Type (int, string, etc.). I don't want to instantiate the class. Any suggestions? Thanks

Tried (below) but using typeof() says MyClassVariable is variable used as a type. I don't have an instance of the class either.

```
typeof(MyClassVariable).GetProperty(MyPropertyVariable).PropertyType.ToString();
```

Comment: uh... yeah, reflection? You already included the tag. What happened when you tried? Where are you stuck, what can we help you with?

Comment: Start with `typeof(mytype)` instead of `myobj.GetType()`.

Comment: `Type.GetType`, `Type.GetProperty`. Neither "instantiates the class", but you do, of course, need a `Type` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var typeString = "System.String";
var propertyString = "Length";

var type = Type.GetType(typeString).GetProperty(propertyString).PropertyType.Name;

Console.WriteLine($"{typeString}.{propertyString} is of type {type}");
```

Prints:

> System.String.Length is of type Int32

Comment: I can reproduce your example and it works great. When I try it with my class GetType returns null. I'm using the AssemblyQualifiedName for the class. Should I be using something else? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The `AssemblyQualifiedName` should work, assuming your assembly was referenced.